# How to expect if a limit exists before attempting squeeze theorem

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, expectation

From this video, I've learned to expect if a limit exists or not is by comparing the combined power on the numerator is bigger than than the combined power on the denominator.

For example, when considering limit as $(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)$the rational function 
$$\frac{3x^2y}{x^2 + y^2}$$

The numerator has an exponential power of three ($x^2 * y)$ whereas the denominator has an exponential power of only 2.

However, I tried to use this intuition to surmise the existence of a limit as$(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)$ for the rational function $\frac{x^4 - 4y^2}{x^2 + 2y^2}$.

As it has an exponential power of 4 on the numerator and an exponential power of 2 on the denominator, I expected the limit to exist. After struggling to prove this using the squeeze theorem, I reassessed using the path test, which quickly proved that it does not.

**What are ways of quickly assessing whether we can expect a limit to exist?**

Comment: You need the lowest powered term in the numerator to be greater than the highest powered term in the denominator.  The lowest powered term in $(x^4+4y^2)$ is $4y^2$ and too small to force the limit to converge at $0.$

Comment: I see - so the rule of thumb is the lowest powered term in the numerator has  to be greater than the highest powered term in the denominator ? Not comparing the overall exponential power of numerator vs denominator, as I had thought?

Comment: also for the equation, $\frac{5y^4cos^2x}{x^4 + y^4}$ -- do we have to compare the lowest/highest power of the same term? In other words, do I compare $y^4$ on top vs $y^4$ on bottom - or can I say that because $cos^2$ is a smaller power than $y^4$, I can expect the limit to not exist?

Comment: Don't get to wedded to  simple rules.  $cos^2 x$ is not going to $0$ as $(x,y),$  so you should just disregard that factor, and treat it like it is a constant.  And as you observed in the original post if you have $\frac {x^ny^m}{x^a+ y^b}$ you can consider the power of the numerator to be $(m+n)$  but if you have $\frac {x^n+y^m}{x^a+ y^b}$ then the power of the numerator (for this calculation) is  $\min(m,n)$

Comment: And if the denominator is $x^a + y^b$ then the power of the denominator is $max(a, b)$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Using polar coordinates 
$$x=r\cos (t) \;\;\; y=r\sin (t) $$

the multivariate function becomes

$$f (x,y)=g (r,t)=3r\sin (t)\cos (t) $$

as $r\to 0$,  $g (r,t) $ goes to zero for all $t $. So the limit exists and is zero.

Comment: Yes, I understand solving it using substitution. I'm asking about intuition before one would try substitution, squeeze theorem, epsilon-delta, etc